# Merge the hierarchies

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-synonyms

There are a few hierarchy tags:

[hierarchy](/questions/tagged/hierarchy) (859 questions):

> For issues relating to creating, maintaining, or displaying a
>   hierarchy of data or resources, etc.

[hierarchical-data](/questions/tagged/hierarchical-data) (559 questions):

> For questions relating to hierarchical or nested data.

[hierarchical](/questions/tagged/hierarchical) (148 questions);

> For issues relating to arranging data and/or resources in a hierarchy

These all appear to be the same and should be merged and synonymised.

Potentially [hierarchical-trees](/questions/tagged/hierarchical-trees) and [hierarchical-query](/questions/tagged/hierarchical-query) could also be included though I'm not convinced of the query especially.

Comment: I agree with your assessment of these tags needing to be merged. Unrelated: I think these tags are all only marginally useful to begin with.